# Search for any given string using JAVA REGEX

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a generic method that will search a file for a given string and replace it with another string. I am using java regex for the same

```java
patternMatcher = Pattern.compile(searchString);
while ((line = readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher regexMatcher = patternMatcher.matcher(line);
       if (regexMatcher.lookingAt()) {
          line = regexMatcher.replaceAll(replaceString);
```

..so on

This logic works as long as the search string is in the beginning of each line in the file. otherwise the pattern matching does not occur. Can anyone please suggest a solution?

for eg. My search String is "This" and Replace string is "That" 
Input file contains: `This is not This funny` 
Output: `That is not That funny`

But when 
Input file contains: `007 This is not This funny` 
Output: `007 This is not This funny`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be...?

```
patternMatcher = Pattern.compile(searchString);
while ((line = readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher regexMatcher = patternMatcher.matcher(line);
       while (regexMatcher.find()) {
          line = regexMatcher.replaceAll(replaceString);
```

Take into account that the quatifier may affect the results, perhapaps the search string should be "(this)+" or "(this)+?".

Comment: @user1384205 You must upvote the answers that work for you and choose one as your final answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for a constant string and not for a pattern, there's a number of reasons why you shouldn't use regex:

- The user might type in some character that has a special meaning in regex grammar.
- Regular expressions are slow compared to substring searching.
- You don't want to allow the user more features (using regex matching) than you intend to.

Use `String.indexOf` and/or `String.replace` instead.

```
while ((line = readLine()) != null)
    if (line.indexOf(searchString) != -1 )
        line.replace(searchString, replaceString);
```

Comment: The files im working with sometimes run to several MBs and the application is very io intensive. The reason I decided to use regex against string manipulation was the same since i'd be reading the stream instead of reading it line by line. Please correct me if im worng.

Comment: If you want good IO performance, have a look at `java.nio` (new I/O). If you want to read a line with NIO, use `BufferedReader.readLine()` on the NIO stream. All this has nothing to do with whether you'll choose to use regex or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Java, but as per the docs, `lookingAt` looks at the beginning of the string.  I would just skip looking for the match and blindly run `replaceAll` regardless of whether there is a match; it will replace nothing if there is no match.

If for some reason you need to look for a match before attempting to replace (which is wasteful), the correct function is `find`.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: Thanks a ton. lookingAt was a wrong usage in my case. find works well.

Comment: Keep in mind that `String.replaceAll()` compiles a regex out of the search string. If you don't need this, use `String.replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

If memory is not an issue, you can read the entire file as String and use `public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` in String API.